# Eloquent: get only the date from timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, timestamp

I want to get all the entries of a specific day for a user.. I don't know how to format the query.

```
public function getEntry()
{
    $entries = Journal::where('id', '=', Auth::id())
    ->where('created_at', '=', '\Carbon\Carbon::now()->format("l j F Y")')
    ->get()->first();
    return view('home')->with(compact('entries'));
}
```

I do not know how to format that 'created_at' to match the server time. Any help will be largely appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `whereDate()` to get all entries for the specific day:

```
->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today());
```

Or use `whereBetween()`:

```
->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfDay(), Carbon::now()->endOfDay()])
```

Or simple `where()`:

```
->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->startOfDay())
->where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->endOfDay())
```